# Card size not being adjusted when wrapped in a container

Tags: flutter

In my flutter app I have a `GridView` in which I list cards. In the cards I want to have an image and some text. I am trying to do this as follows:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return HomeState();
  }
}

class HomeState extends State<Home>{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                  colors: [
                    Colors.green,
                    Colors.teal,
                  ]
                )
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 65),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        width: 100,
                        height: 100,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          shape: BoxShape.circle,
                          border: Border.all(color: Colors.white60, width:  2.0)
                        ),
                        padding:  EdgeInsets.all(8),
                        child: CircleAvatar(
                          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                          child: Icon(Icons.restaurant, size: 120,),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ]
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 8,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "Genesis Technologies",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 22,
                      color: Colors.white
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 6,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "Please take the following precautions",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 16,
                      color: Colors.white70
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 350),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                  topRight: Radius.circular(20),
                )
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 250),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(30),
                  topRight: Radius.circular(30)
                )
              ),
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                child: GridView(
                  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      height: 200,
                      width: 100,
                      child: Card(
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)
                      ),
                      elevation: 10,
                      child: Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.all(4),
                        color: Colors.white,
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Icon(Icons.restaurant, size: 120,),
                            Text(
                              "Cover your mouth and nose when yous sneeze or cough",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    ),
                    Card(
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)
                      ),
                      elevation: 10,
                      child: Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.all(4),
                        color: Colors.white,
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Icon(Icons.restaurant, size: 120,),
                            Text(
                              "Avoid touching your face with unwashed hands",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Card(
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)
                      ),
                      elevation: 10,
                      child: Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.all(4),
                        color: Colors.white,
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Icon(Icons.restaurant, size: 120,),
                            Text(
                              "Stay home if you don't need to get out for critical matters",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                )
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
    );
    }

}
```

And this renders the list of cards fine. My problem is that the cards bottom is being overflowed. I wrap the card in a container to fix this which looks like the follows:

```
    Container(
        height: 200,
        width: 100,
        child: Card(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)
        ),
        elevation: 10,
        child: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(4),
            color: Colors.white,
            child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: <Widget>[
                    Icon(Icons.restaurant, size: 120,),
                     Text(
                        "Some text here",
                         style: TextStyle(
                             fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                         ),
                    ),
                ],
           ),
       ),
  ),
),
```

I don't understand why this is happening. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What is the point using `Stack` without `Positioned` ?

Comment: @LonelyWolf None really. Does it bring this kind of behavior?

Comment: Not really... Just first thing what hit my face. Just quickly from the code.. try to get rid of the first container and set height and width in your second container, also try to set mainAxisSize in your column to min. It would be easier to help if you could provide a reproducible code which we could simply copy and paste to try it

Comment: @LonelyWolf I have edited the code to make the first code reproducible.You might need to remove the images tho. And I  can't get rid of the first container cause it is needed for the `UI` I am trying to achieve.

Comment: remove images or change them to something else... Reproducible means that I don't have to import or change something to duplicate the issue you are having

Comment: @LonelyWolf I have changed all the images to Icons

Comment: good I've got it.. now what exactly you want to change? Only one card inside your of your GridView?

Comment: @LonelyWolf No I want to have several cards. I want the cards to increase their height and not get overflown

Answer (score 1):

ok... I usual don't do that but I had to rework the whole structure because most of the things didn't make any sense. Now I don't really understand.. Why do you want cards to increase size to not overflow.. Did you mean decrease size? The cards in your grid view will be always the same because you use grid view. You have set crossAxisCount to 2 so 2 items in x axis and square.. If you add more, then on smaller screen they will be accessible by scrolling and will not overflow. I have set position of the container where you have all your cards from the top to 1/3 of the screen height which perhaps is better then hardcoding it to fixed size as you had. Try it and let me know if you need to adjust it in any other way.

**UPDATE**

```
Scaffold(
      body: Column(children: [
        Flexible(
          flex: 2,
          child: Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [
              Colors.green,
              Colors.teal,
            ])),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Flexible(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: FractionallySizedBox(
                    heightFactor: 0.5,
                    child: Container(
                      width: 100,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          shape: BoxShape.circle,
                          border:
                              Border.all(color: Colors.white60, width: 2.0)),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      child: CircleAvatar(
                        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.restaurant,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 8,
                ),
                Text(
                  "Genesis Technologies",
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 22,
                      color: Colors.white),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 6,
                ),
                Text(
                  "Please take the following precautions",
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.white70),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Flexible(
          flex: 3,
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [
              Colors.green,
              Colors.teal,
            ])),
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(30),
                      topRight: Radius.circular(30))),
              child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                  child: GridView(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                        crossAxisCount: 2),
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Card(
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
                        elevation: 10,
                        child: Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.all(4),
                          color: Colors.white,
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Icon(
                                Icons.restaurant,
                                size: 120,
                              ),
                              Text(
                                "Cover your mouth and nose when yous sneeze or cough",
                                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Card(
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
                        elevation: 10,
                        child: Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.all(4),
                          color: Colors.white,
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Icon(
                                Icons.restaurant,
                                size: 120,
                              ),
                              Text(
                                "Avoid touching your face with unwashed hands",
                                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Card(
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
                        elevation: 10,
                        child: Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.all(4),
                          color: Colors.white,
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Icon(
                                Icons.restaurant,
                                size: 120,
                              ),
                              Text(
                                "Stay home if you don't need to get out for critical matters",
                                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  )),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ]),
    );
```

Comment: I am getting this error .`MediaQuery.of() called with a context that does not contain a MediaQuery.`

Comment: that is hard to fix without other code mostly where is your home screen called from and so on. For now just replace `MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 3`  with fixed number lets say 300. I personally wouldn't use stack in your case because you really need to know where to use it otherwise it will make more harm then good...

Comment: Try my updated code... this approach is much better for different display sizes.. You can test it by rotating simulator display